# Continuous representations of topological groups on Banach spaces

Tags: rt.representation-theory, banach-spaces, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group and let $\rho:G\rightarrow\text{GL}(V)$ be
a linear representation of $G$ on a Banach space $V$. The representation
is called *strongly continuous* if the map $g\mapsto\rho_{g}(v)$
is norm-continuous for every $v\in V$. Similarly, it is *weakly
continuous* if the map is weakly continuous, i.e. if $g\mapsto\phi(\rho_{g}(v))$
is continuous for every $v\in V$, $\phi\in V^{\ast}$.

By the footnote (3) on page 1382 in **[1]**, if $G$ is locally compact,
the strong continuity of $\rho$ is equivalent to its weak continuity.
This appears to go back to de Leeuw and Glicksberg, even though the
original proof seems to be flawed. I am wondering what happens for
general topological groups. Does the statement still hold (for broader
classes)? Are there examples of groups where it is not true?

**[1]** Shtern, Alexander Isaakovich. "*[Criteria
for weak and strong continuity of representations of topological groups
in Banach spaces](https://www.mathnet.ru/eng/sm/v193/i9/p139).*" Sbornik: Mathematics 193, No. 9 (2002):
1381-1396, [MR1936860](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1936860), [Zbl 1044.22003](https://zbmath.org/1044.22003).

Comment: @TarasBanakh This question can be related to the results from your current seminar talk.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thank you for turning my attention to this question. As a comment, I can recommend to look at this preprint https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.02481, which contains many (general) results on the automatic continuity of measurable homomorphisms  between topological groups. So, it may happen that some of such results will be applicable to this question.